BadCredentials error while authenticating even while correct email/password
Article used to implement auth
    fun authenticate(loginDTO: LoginDTO): LoginResponse {
        val authentication =
            authenticationManager.authenticate(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginDTO.email, loginDTO.password))
        if (authentication.isAuthenticated) {
            val refreshToken = refreshTokenService.createRefreshToken(loginDTO.email)
            return LoginResponse(jwtService.generateToken(loginDTO.email), refreshToken.token)
        } else {
            throw UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid User Request")
        }
    }

Just this called on log in route. It shows error at the comment line
@Component
class JwtAuthenticationFilter(
    private val userDetailsService: UserDetailsService,
    private val jwtService: JwtService,
    private val handlerExceptionResolver: HandlerExceptionResolver
) : OncePerRequestFilter() {


    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain
    ) {
        val header = request.getHeader("Authorization")
        val username: String?
        val token: String?

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response) <--- receiving BadCredentials error here as header is null
            return
        }
        // remaining isn't useful for problem, didn't include to make message less messy
    }
}

I understand that while logging in client won't give an authorization token but we will provide client with one but the above mentioned article does so.
Tell me if i should share other class too.
Edit- Configuration
@Configuration
class Config(
    private val service: UserService,
) {
    @Bean
    fun userDetailsService(): UserDetailsService =
        UserDetailsService { username ->
            val userDetail: UserDetails
            runBlocking {
                val user =
                    service.getUser(email = username) ?: throw UsernameNotFoundException("Email address is Invalid")
                userDetail =
                    User.withUsername(user.email).password(getPasswordEncoder().encode(user.loginPassword)).build()
            }
            userDetail
        }

    @Bean
    fun getPasswordEncoder() = BCryptPasswordEncoder()

    @Bean
    fun authenticationManager(config: AuthenticationConfiguration): AuthenticationManager =
        config.authenticationManager ?: throw Exception()

    @Bean
    fun authenticationProvider(): AuthenticationProvider {
        val authProvider = DaoAuthenticationProvider()

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService())
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder())

        return authProvider
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration(
    private val authenticationEntryPoint: JwtAuthEntryPoint,
    private val jwtAuthenticationFilter: JwtAuthenticationFilter,
    private val authenticationProvider: AuthenticationProvider
) {
    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http.csrf { it.disable() }
            .authorizeHttpRequests {
                    it.requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
            }
            .exceptionHandling { it.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint) }
            .sessionManagement { it.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) }
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(
                jwtAuthenticationFilter,
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java
            )
        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun corsConfigurationSource(): CorsConfigurationSource {
        val configuration = CorsConfiguration()

        configuration.allowedOrigins = listOf("http://localhost:8080")
        configuration.allowedMethods = listOf("GET", "POST")
        configuration.allowedHeaders = listOf("Authorization", "Content-Type")

        val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration)

        return source
    }
}

Edit - This is my repository

Please add your configuration.

What is going to call authenticate? Why are you encoding the password upon retrieval? You should store the hashes not plain text passwords (this basically defeats the whole purpose of having a PasswordEncoder in the first place. It they are encoded you are now double encoding it.

@M.Deinum authenticate is being called in login function, annotated with @PostMapping("/login"). it's the only function being called there.
As of hashing, I am a beginner and i have watched wrong tutorial. So i must store password in DB hashed. As of comparison i must hash incoming password(in loginDTO) and then compare?
This is my repository

No you don't need to hash the incoming password it won't even work as it will result in a different hash (it is just a one time hash). Spring Security will take care of the comparison.

@M.Deinum Hey, i solved the problem. Great thanks to u. I was facing it from 4 days. I can finally breath.
